# How to confirm if an ISO is UEFI bootable - An UEFI Rescue disk ISO does not boot in UEFI Mode - VMware

Tags: ubuntu, boot, uefi, livecd

I have downloaded  **All in one – rescue disk** (ISO file) from an internet site. The site claims that it’s based on Ubuntu 64 and is UEFI Boot capable. The ISO does open in 7z and when opened in Power ISO app it shows Bootable Status.
I have created an Ubuntu 64 Based Virtual Machine using VMWare Player 12 (no Guest OS installation yet) (Host OS is Windows 7 64) and I am trying to boot this VM using the ISO file in EFI mode.

I have correctly selected the ISO as CD Drive image and added this line `firmware = “efi”` in the VMware config file.

However the system fails to boot from ISO in UEFI Mode. Change the mode to bios and it seamlessly boots. Am  I missing something or the ISO is actually not EFI Bootable?

How do I further confirm if the ISO is not UEFI bootable without physical UEFI hardware like a UEFI complaint PC or laptop?

I have even tried entering the Firmware in VM and manually selecting CD drive as boot option but it does not boot.

[image]

Comment: It must have an EFI folder with a proper EFI file inside. Otherwise it can't be used with UEFI.

Comment: Yes it has the EFI folder with BOOTx64.EFI and grubx64.efi files in it. Still it skips UEFI Boot! I have Ubuntu 15.04 64 ISO that flawlessly boots with same settings in UEFI mode though, that somehow makes me wonder if something is wrong with the bootable ISO somewhere.